# Split all x_i in X into K groups s.t. var(sum(x in k) for k in K) is minimized

Tags: algorithm

I have X positive numbers, indexed x_i. Each x_i needs to go into one of K groups (where K is predetermined). Let S_j be the sum of all x_i in K_j. I need to allocate all x_i such that the variance of all S_j is minimized. What algorithm accomplishes this? I'm sure there is some class of algorithms addressing a problem like this, but I don't know it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems). Given that most problems of this kind are `NP-hard`, you are unlikely to find an efficient optimal algorithm.

[Multiprocessor scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling) which tries to minimize the size of the largest group has a simple 4/3 - 1/(3K) approximation alrogithm (from 
[Bounds on Multiprocessing Timing Anomalies](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.90.8131&rep=rep1&type=pdf)):

Sorts the number and then assigns them to the smallest group so far.